# unrecognized selector sent to instance in [FBSDKModelManager enable]

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk-next

I upgrade expo project from 47 to 48 then this error occur from nowhere.
It make app crash when starting. Nothing much in project was changed.
Even if I try to disable all code and return only empty view in javascript side.
The crash still occur.

```
    -[__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

    0 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab7a8e44 42CCFC7B-FF32-3D25-8F01-CCB2AD843A8B + 40516
    1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00000001a493f8d8 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab91d81c 42CCFC7B-FF32-3D25-8F01-CCB2AD843A8B + 1566748
    3 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab7bef50 42CCFC7B-FF32-3D25-8F01-CCB2AD843A8B + 130896
    4 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab827320 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
    5 FBSDKCoreKit 0x000000010591917c __27-[FBSDKModelManager enable]_block_invoke + 500
    6 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000105e85ff0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    7 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000105e87b60 _dispatch_once_callout + 136
    8 FBSDKCoreKit 0x0000000105918f84 -[FBSDKModelManager enable] + 104
    9 FBSDKCoreKit 0x00000001058de078 __43-[FBSDKAppEvents     fetchServerConfiguration:]_block_invoke_4 + 56
    10 FBSDKCoreKit 0x00000001059746e4 $s12FBSDKCoreKit15_FeatureManagerC5check_15completionBlockySo12FBSDKFeatureV_ySbctFys5Error_pSgcfU_TA + 44
    11 FBSDKCoreKit 0x00000001059735c8 $ss5Error_pSgIegg_So7NSErrorCSgIeyBy_TR + 52
    12 FBSDKCoreKit 0x00000001059034b8 +[FBSDKGateKeeperManager loadGateKeepers:] + 604
    13 FBSDKCoreKit 0x00000001059734e0 $s12FBSDKCoreKit15_FeatureManagerC5check_15completionBlockySo12FBSDKFeatureV_ySbctF + 660
    14 FBSDKCoreKit 0x0000000105973644 $s12FBSDKCoreKit15_FeatureManagerC5check_15completionBlockySo12FBSDKFeatureV_ySbctFTo + 96
    15 FBSDKCoreKit 0x00000001058ddd60 __43-[FBSDKAppEvents fetchServerConfiguration:]_block_invoke_2 + 960
    16 FBSDKCoreKit 0x000000010592e21c -[FBSDKServerConfigurationManager loadServerConfigurationWithCompletionBlock:] + 1420
    17 FBSDKCoreKit 0x00000001058dd980 __43-[FBSDKAppEvents fetchServerConfiguration:]_block_invoke + 128
    18 FBSDKCoreKit 0x00000001058e27bc -[FBSDKAppEventsConfigurationManager _processResponse:error:] + 608
    19 FBSDKCoreKit 0x000000010590dbbc -[FBSDKGraphRequestMetadata invokeCompletionHandlerForConnection:withResults:error:] + 152
    20 FBSDKCoreKit 0x000000010590ab0c __82-[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection processResultBody:error:metadata:canNotifyDelegate:]_block_invoke + 144
    21 FBSDKCoreKit 0x000000010590aa00 -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection processResultBody:error:metadata:canNotifyDelegate:] + 700
    22 FBSDKCoreKit 0x000000010590a5e0 __65-[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection _completeWithResults:networkError:]_block_invoke + 496
    23 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab7a9350 42CCFC7B-FF32-3D25-8F01-CCB2AD843A8B + 41808
    24 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab7c4680 42CCFC7B-FF32-3D25-8F01-CCB2AD843A8B + 153216
    25 FBSDKCoreKit 0x000000010590a310 -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection _completeWithResults:networkError:] + 548
    26 FBSDKCoreKit 0x00000001059094a8 -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection completeFBSDKURLSessionWithResponse:data:networkError:] + 800
    27 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000105e8453c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    28 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000105e85ff0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    29 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000105e96800 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1196
    30 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000105e96344 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
    31 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab8396c8 42CCFC7B-FF32-3D25-8F01-CCB2AD843A8B + 632520
    32 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab81b02c 42CCFC7B-FF32-3D25-8F01-CCB2AD843A8B + 507948
    33 CoreFoundation 0x00000001ab81feb0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
    34 GraphicsServices 0x00000001e5a15368 GSEventRunModal + 164
    35 UIKitCore 0x00000001add15668 CF21AD9C-EFBF-3961-A7C0-54BD30CEFEA9 + 3806824
    36 UIKitCore 0x00000001add152cc UIApplicationMain + 340
    37 MyApplication 0x0000000100678990 main + 96
    38 dyld 0x00000001ca118960 4B042F28-0D14-30EC-A1DE-3DBB10866AD7 + 88416
```

Environment information provided here

```
System:
OS: macOS 13.2.1
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
Memory: 93.28 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 18.15.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
npm: 9.2.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
Watchman: 2022.10.17.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.12.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
Android SDK:
Android NDK: 22.1.7171670
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2022.1 AI-221.6008.13.2211.9619390
Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 18.0.1.1 - /usr/bin/javac
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
react-native: 0.71.3 => 0.71.3
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
react-native: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was changed after removed application on iPhone.
This error may related to running lldb process.